# How can I access the complete public record of a USPTO patent?

Tags: uspto

I read in this [answer](https://patents.stackexchange.com/a/24778/3789) by [George White](https://patents.stackexchange.com/users/3076/george-white):

> But, taking the question literally, no, there is not an easy way to see the applications filed by a particular registered practitioner. **It is buried in the complete public record of each case** but not on the face of the document that is searched. In patent work we do take things literally. Not every application turns into an issued patent.

How can I access the complete public record of a USPTO patent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always used the US Public Pair, but that is being discontinued. It is being replaced with [USPTO Patent Center](https://patentcenter.uspto.gov). You can search by application number, patent number, PCT number, publication number or international design registration number. Documents related to the case are pretty easily accessed from there.